# com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 15))

Tags: java, xml-parsing, axiom

I am extracting data from a XML using the axiom. 
But I'm getting above error because of having CTRL-CHAR (eg : â, €, ¢, “, ”, ™, ’, – etc) in the XML. 
Can any body help me to replace all the CTRL-SHARs to avoid the above error.

Comment: The CTLR-CHAR doesn't refer to those characters you've listed, but to non-printable control characters below U+0020 which (with a few exceptions, notably CR, LF and tab) are not allowed in XML 1.0 documents.  If your source documents contain such characters then they're not well-formed XML.

Comment: @ Ian : Yep, but the exceptions said them as the CTRL-CHAR isn't it? When I simply replace the detected caharacters one after another it works fine. But I need a handy and robust method for this.

Comment: The exception says "code 15", i.e. U+000F.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using following method in this case. But I think there must be a better way than  this.

```
public static String removeNonUtf8CompliantCharacters( final String inString ) {
        if (null == inString ) return null;
        byte[] byteArr = inString.getBytes();
        for ( int i=0; i < byteArr.length; i++ ) {
            byte ch= byteArr[i]; 
            // remove any characters outside the valid UTF-8 range as well as all control characters
            if ( !(ch < 0x00FD && ch > 0x001F) || ch =='&' || ch=='#') {
                byteArr[i]=' ';
            }
        }
        return new String( byteArr );
    }
```